# Issue in binding social accounts with local account in web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, passport.js

**App description:** 
User can sign up with credentials and get authorization and refresh token from a server, they're saved respectively in session and local storage. Axios is configured to intercept 401 status response and then make a new request to separete endpoint with refresh token as a payload. Server verify refresh token and respond with new authorization token that is set as a default header to every axios request. User can also login with social accounts (fb, g+, github) which are implemented using passport lib.

**Task description:** 
As a logged user I can connect my current account with my social account. This case is included in [passport documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authorize/).

**Problem description:**
Requests to route specified in documentation:

```
 app.get('/connect/twitter',
  passport.authorize('twitter-authz', { failureRedirect: '/account' })
 );
```

can be done only by redirection with `<a href='/connect/twitter'>`,

XMLHttpRequest is not possible due to CORS error (eg. [example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/155#issuecomment-204086618)). And this is a problem, I can't send auth token using simple redirection so server can't decode token and get local user info and so can't add updated user data (with social account data) to database..

[Source code](https://github.com/frozenfroggie/Nightlife)

[Http address](https://vast-everglades-58513.herokuapp.com)

PS. Sorry for bad english, I will appreciate any help!